# How to make existing fields available to be created as instances on other content types etc.?

Tags: entities

I have created a custom module that simply creates a set of standard fields via a .install file. It's very simple, basically:

```
foreach (my_fields_fields() as $field) {
  if (!field_info_field($field['field_name'])) {
    field_create_field($field);
  }
}

function my_fields_fields() {
  return array(
    'field_my_first_name' => array(
      'field_name' => 'field_my_first_name',
      'type' => 'text',
    ),
    ...
```

On enabling the module, I can see that the fields have tables in the database. However, if I navigate to `admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields` and drop down `- Select an existing field -` in the `Add existing field` section, the fields are not present.

I don't want to create any instances of my fields in my module (do I?) because it is for other users/systems to create field instances if they want to.

How do I get Drupal to make my fields available? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An 'existing field' in that context is one that already has an instance, it doesn't refer to the existence of the field *type*. Until an instance is created, it doesn't exist as such.

Your field will be available to add as a new field as usual; if you want it to appear under 'Add existing field' section, you'll need to create an instance of it first.